# Como montar uma lista foreach em posições diferentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lógica

Como montar uma lista utilizando o foreach para mudar o posicionamento da imagem.
Se meu count for 1, posiciona a imagem do lado esquerdo, se meu count for 2 posiciona imagem do lado direita, segue meu código.

```
<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model.DadosEmpresa)
{

    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count == 1)
    {
        <section class="row align-items-center padding-bottom-2x">

            <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="mt-30 hidden-md-up"></div>
                <h2>@Html.Raw(item.Texto)</h2>
                <p class="text-sm">
                    @Html.Raw(item.TextoDestaque)
                </p>
            </div>



        </section>

    }
    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count == 2)
    {
        <section class="row align-items-center padding-bottom-2x">

            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="mt-30 hidden-md-up"></div>
                <h2>@Html.Raw(item.Texto)</h2>
                <p class="text-sm">
                    @Html.Raw(item.TextoDestaque)
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>



        </section>

    }



    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count == 3)
    {
        <section class="row align-items-center padding-bottom-2x">

            <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>
            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="mt-30 hidden-md-up"></div>
                <h2>@Html.Raw(item.Texto)</h2>
                <p class="text-sm">
                    @Html.Raw(item.TextoDestaque)
                </p>
            </div>



        </section>

    }

    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count == 4)
    {
        <section class="row align-items-center padding-bottom-2x">

            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="mt-30 hidden-md-up"></div>
                <h2>@Html.Raw(item.Texto)</h2>
                <p class="text-sm">
                    @Html.Raw(item.TextoDestaque)
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>



        </section>

    }

}
```

Comment: Parece que dois itens são iguais já pode refatorar isso.

Answer (score 0):

Não me parece haver erro no código apresentado, apesar de poder ser reescrito. Aparentemente é um problema nos seus dados: `Model.DadosEmpresa.Count` deve ter sempre o mesmo valor.
Neste fiddle é possível ver que o código HTML funciona como descrito: https://jsfiddle.net/snd57jtg/

Em relação à refatoração, olhando bem rapidamente, seria possível reduzir o código para algo como

```cs
<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model.DadosEmpresa)
{
  <section class="row align-items-center padding-bottom-2x">
    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count % 2 == 1)
    {
      <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>
    }
            <div class="col-md-7 text-md-left text-center">
                <div class="mt-30 hidden-md-up"></div>
                <h2>@Html.Raw(item.Texto)</h2>
                <p class="text-sm">
                    @Html.Raw(item.TextoDestaque)
                </p>
            </div>
    @if (Model.DadosEmpresa.Count % 2 == 0)
    {
      <div class="col-md-5"><img class="d-block w-270 m-auto" src="@item.Imagem" alt="Foto Empresa"></div>
    }
  </section>
}
```